# I am getting an "Installation Failed" message when I install my app with InstallShield. Is there a way for me to see why it failed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, installshield, failed-installation

For clarity, the application still works after the Installation Failed message, so it appears to be installed correctly. I just can't release the application if people are going to see this message whether the app works or not.

I have no idea why it's showing me that message.

I'm using InstallShield SE (comes with Visual Studio 2010).

**Update:**
I've added a sample installation log for a failed installation on Windows 8:

[part 1] http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=Qssr
[part 2] http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=8wytN

Can anyone decipher this? I've searched for the text "Installation Failed" but I can't find it, and searches for e.g. "error" don't return anything meaningful.

Just to note this occurrs on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8.

**Update 2:**

Just to compound this issue a bit further, the following is a log which doesn't contain the text that @Yan Sklyarenko pointed out from the first file. So I'm seeing the same issue but the second log file doesn't mention it. (also, the second log file is 2MB which is why I had to host it on my google docs drive.)

Anyone have any ideas wtf is up with InstallShield?

http://docs.google.com/open?id=0B813RziGagi_aldUNFJqLTNzYVE

Comment: You should create a log file to see where is problem.
If you have msi then: **msiexec /i MyApplication.msi /l*v install_log.txt** 
If you have an exe installer then: **Setup.exe /Debuglog"install_log.txt"**

Answer (score 3):

Your log contains the following line:

> User cancelled installation.

Usually this means, well, that the user cancelled installation. :) But that's obviously not your case.

I've managed to find [the following knowledge base article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/installsite/archive/2007/04/18/830140.aspx). Basically, it has a warning that a UAC call might time out in case you don't interact with it. In this case it outputs the error you see and considers that the user cancelled installation:

```
 MSI (s) (A8:A0) [12:32:25:129]: MSI_LUA: Elevation required to install product, will prompt for credentials 
 MSI (s) (A8:A0) [12:32:46:578]: MSI_LUA: Credential Request return = 0x800704C7 
 User cancelled installation.
```

Probably, the UAC window just not appeared in front? If it was a background window you could likely miss it. 
Here is [one more link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa369758%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which might be useful (see the only comment to that article). You can investigate how turning creating checkpoints on and off can influence the behavior.

And by the way, Windows XP can't have this issue as it doesn't have UAC feature. So, it might be something else.

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes sense. I'm wondering however, why is it that the application still runs if the installation requires elevated privileges? Can you determine this from the log file?

Comment: Well... the log says the installation was cancelled, hence I don't understand how the application might at all exist on the target PC after this... Are you sure it is not the previous version of the application?

Comment: Hi Yan, yes this was a clean installation. I'm quickly coming to dislike installshield. It's showing me very inconsistent results. I've linked to another log file that was produced by installshield after a different installation and there's no mention of "User cancelled installation" as you pointed out in the first one.

Comment: Sorry Yan, I am not seeing this until now. I was hoping that service could host the file because it is 2MB but I guess not. I've put it into my Google Drive account instead and made it public. If you want to see it, it's here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B813RziGagi_aldUNFJqLTNzYVE. Google Drive seems to think it's an mp3 file, but it's not - it's a .log file.

Comment: @DaveDev, it's strange, but the latest log says the application was installed fine. I don't see any critical errors in it. How does the application behave after that install? Does it start? Does it work as expected? What makes you think it is not working right?

Comment: It works perfectly after the installation in all cases, whether I see the Installation Failed message or not.

Comment: @DaveDev, anyway, the last log you posted doesn't contain a warning sign to me... I would say it completed successfully.

Comment: Ok.. this is frustrating!! I can't rightfully award you the full bounty because it doesn't actually solve the issue, but you've been very helpful and I appreciate that. I've upvoted you and I can see that you've already got 2 upvotes anyway so according to the rules of the bounty you'll be awarded half the points. I'm going to have to ask the question again and increase the bounty to 100 but before I do that I'll have to get some more solid cases of this happening with the log files for each. Thanks for taking the time here, and I'm sorry it couldn't be worth more to you.

Comment: I understand, this answer doesn't deserve any amount of bounty, but that's how the system works... It would be great if you narrow the problem down - I'll definitely have a look at it. Good luck!